# What is the grammar of following sentence? (maybe adverb clause)

Tags: grammar

Could you please explain to me the grammar of the bold part of the following sentence?

> The little boy might find it difficult to hold the hammer the same way his father does, **grasping it at the end of the handle.**

I am not sure whether this is an adverb clause. I'd like to know what sentence can be reduced to this clause.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's a gerund-participial clause functioning as a supplementary adjunct. The finite equivalent is "he grasps it at the end of the handle".

Comment: Syntactically, ***the same way his father does*** and ***grasping it at the end of the handle*** both look like adverbial clauses to me - which could in principle be specified in the opposite sequence, or either of them could simply be discarded without affecting the basic syntax of the utterance. You could precede the first clause with ***in***, or the second with ***by*** - but both those prepositions are optional, and it makes no difference to the meaning whether they're present or not.

Comment: @FredoonFarokh I was just presenting the finite alternant without any attempt to link it to the main clause which, as it happens, would be difficult here. That's the whole point of non-finite clauses: they step in where finite ones are either impossible or at least clumsy.

Comment: Looking at this again some time later, I've just realised the cited text is *ambiguous*. I initially took it for granted the reference was to *the father* grasping the hammer by the end of the handle (which the boy might not be strong enough to do). But now I see that final clause could in principle apply to *the boy* - in which case it could be "fronted": ***Grasping it at the end of the handle**, the little boy might find it difficult to hold the hammer the same way his father does* (I don't care how we unpack the *meaning* there - the point I'm making is it's ***syntactically valid***).